# What weapons can I legally carry for self-defence in New York City?

Tags: united-states, self-defense, weapons, new-york-city

I've been on the receiving end of racist verbal attacks regarding COVID-19.

I've already reported this to the police; they advise me not to engage with the offenders.

However, I suspect that things might escalate, I feel physically threatened in my own neighborhood at this point.

What weapons could I carry on my person, in New York City, in the event that I had to protect myself?

Do I have a right to buy a gun? Carry a baseball bat? A knife? Brass knuckles?

Comment: Neither COVID-19, nor being target of racist verbal attacks, nor the combination of both make you more eligible to carry weapons in NYC than anyone else. Same laws still apply to everyone.

Comment: Brass knuckles are illegal pretty much every where.

Comment: You can buy a gun if you have a [license or permit](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/nypd/services/law-enforcement/permits-licenses-firearms.page), but the licensing process apparently takes up to six months and approval is not guaranteed.